# Backlight flickers after lid close and switch to battery

Tags: backlight

Ubuntu 12.10 32bit with Fallback DE. I need to set to Classic for Citrix Receiver to work properly.  When screens are maximized with Unity, the mouse is offset.

I can close and re-open the lid if on AC power but on battery, the backlight starts to flash off and on.  Reconnecting the AC stops the flashing.

Power Options set to do nothing on lid close.  Seeing the same issue on three different models of HP/Compaq laptop; nc4200, nc4400 and nc6220, all running 32 bit.

I installed 64 bit on a Compaq 6510b with the same fallback and it is fine.

It is not out of the norm for my users to close the lid, unplug the AC adapter, and then carry the laptop to another location and open the lid, expecting it to work from the battery.

Unplugging the AC adapter does nothing so long as the lid doesn't get closed.

Comment: I guess I should have checked the forum stats before I wasted my time to join. 14,633 questions with no answers

Answer (score 0):

I've found that removing the `gnome-screensaver` package does the trick. I've seen threads about disabling the `vsync` option in CompizConfig for OpenGL settings as well.

With both items done, I can close my laptop and re-open with no hiccup. I have an Intel integrated graphics card on an old HP Compaq NC6120 laptop.